# Python3, problem importing vim from pyVmomi

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6, vmware, pyvmomi

I had a project in PyCharm with python2.7 perfectly working and in it the class VMWare that imported vim from pyVmomi.

I'm reworking it it python3.6, via pip I installed all the needed library but on PyCharm I can't import vim from pyVmomi.

```
Cannot find reference 'vim' in '__init__.py'
```

If I execute the project from command line/terminal it works without problem but I can't execute quickly from pyCharm.

Any idea how to fix it? I follow even other post to check virtual environment configuration and trying to select different version of pyVmomi but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you checked `File - Setting - Project - Project Interpreter`? Do you run the same interpreter in the command line?

Comment: yes I'm pointing to the same one, python3.6